# Solr's TimeZone behaviour differs for EST and PST

Tags: solr, timezone, solr6

I'm using Solr-6.2.1 on windows.

When setting **`set SOLR_TIMEZONE=PST`**, in **solr.in.cmd** file, **dataimport.properties** file saves **`last_index_time`** in **PDT** i.e. **UTC-07:00**.

When setting **`set SOLR_TIMEZONE=EST`**, in **solr.in.cmd** file, **dataimport.properties** file saves **`last_index_time`** in **EST** i.e. **UTC-05:00**.

But

When setting **`set SOLR_TIMEZONE=PDT`** or **`set SOLR_TIMEZONE=EDT`**, in **solr.in.cmd** file, **dataimport.properties** file saves **`last_index_time`** of the **Server's TimeZone**.

I didn't understand why Solr is saving Daylight for PST and not for EST. and why for PDT and EDT it shows time with regarding to the server.

Comment: Are you sure PDT and EDT are valid identifiers? Solr uses Java's TZ library, so my guess is that EDT and PDT aren't considered valid identifiers by themselves? According to [What are the Java Timezone IDs](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/) there is no PDT or EDT on that list. Try using one of the actual identifiers for the area you're trying to implement.

Comment: but it takes PST and EST, behaviour for both is different. When setting timezone as PST, this what I'm getting in dataimport.properties **`#Wed Oct 31 02:52:45 PDT 2018`**. But when setting it as EST result is **`#Wed Oct 31 04:57:27 EST 2018`**. Solr is saving 1 hour as daylight savings for PST while for EST no daylight savings. That is the main problem.

Comment: Not all locations using EST are using EDT. Use the specific location and see if you're getting more sensible results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `EST` and `PST`.  They are there for backwards compatibility reasons.  Instead prefer the ones marked "Canonical" in [the list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  For example:

- Instead of `EST`, for most locations using Eastern Time in the US, use `America/New_York`, or if in Canada use `America/Toronto`
- Instead of `PST`, for most locations using Pacific Time in the US, use `America/Los_Angeles`, or if in Canada use `America/Vancouver`

Using these will allow your software to properly choose standard time or daylight time, depending on the date and time in question.